# Iterate rows and locking coordinates

Tags: python, pandas

I am kind of stuck here and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have a df with columns "Latitude", "Longitude", however with important indexes.
My plan is to lock first row coordinates [Latitude, Longitude] as X, perform formula Y, and do * some other stuff* with the result.
Then I want to lock second row as X, perform Y, third row etc.

```
    Latitude Longitude
3    54.0     130.2
8    53.5    -125.2
9    65.0     120.45
```

As I am a newbie, I tried to use basic For loop and iloc but I managed only to capture index, but not coordinates.

I would need to capture coordinates [Latitude, Longitude] and iterate that for every row.

Also, after doing *some other stuff* with values, I want to put these resulting values back in new df with same order (row and index order as above). I am not sure how to approach this part too.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:
I have been ask to provide the code.

```
for i in df.index:
i==0
d.loc[i]  
i=i+1
```

This is what I had when i asked the question. Tried to figure out how to capture/print the values (coordinates) but unsuccessfully. This code was also before I figured out I will need original indexes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code.

Comment: I am guessing that you're being vague because the operations you are performing on `latitude` and `longitude` are sensitive/private. that's understandable, but without an example of what kind of operations you want to perform,  it's hard to give you a clear answer. however iterating through a DataFrame is not performant so I would avoid that if possible. are you looking to apply some function `f(lat,lon) = value` and store this value in a new column? because if so, you can write a one-liner like `df["output"] = df.apply(lambda row: my_func(row["Latitude"], row["Longitude"]), axis=1)`

Comment: Hey, thank you. It's not really sensitive, but I am trying to work on stuff step by step. I have a list of coordinates with certain geographical data, and I wanted to fill some gaps in geographic data by doing interpolation based on the info of surrounding nearest coordinates. My question is just a smaller step to achieve that goal. Most likely there is easier solution/package for the work I am doing?
I saw other interpolation packages and they work on by interpolating the data between row above and below. I have a lot of data so my nearest coordinates are not positioned like that

Comment: @Kate oh i see... that's an interesting problem. i feel like there is almost certainly a package out there or possibly a function in `geopandas` to accomplish what you want because I feel like this problem has probably been encountered before

Comment: `geopandas` comes highly recommended if you're going to be working with lats/longs in a dataframe. As far as filling in missing data... if your dataset isn't too large, you could even check out `geopy`. The geocoder `Nominatim` is free for limited use, and will supply you with all sorts of information given a pair of lats/longs.